# Bootstrap multi select grouping dynamicaly using array

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

Is there a way to dynamically add grouping in multi select using this formation

```js
var data = [
    {label: "ACNP", value: "ACNP"},
    {label: "test", value: "test"}
];
$("#multiselect").multiselect("dataprovider", data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can now add groups with `dataprovider` thanks to [this pull request](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/pull/281)

See the documentation on [`.multiselect('dataprovider', data)`](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#example18-mushrooms).

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ezyx84xt/)

You can compose like this:

```js
var data = [{
    title: 'First group',
    children: [{ label: 'Cheese', value: 'cheese' }, 
               { label: 'Tomatoes', value: 'tomatoes' }]
    }, {
    title: 'Second group',
    children: [{ label: 'Mozzarella', value: 'mozzarella' }, 
               { label: 'Mushrooms', value: 'mushrooms' }]
}];

$('.multiselect').multiselect('dataprovider', data);
```

```html
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

@KyleMit for me instead of title, label works..

```
var data = [{
    label: 'First group',
    children: [{ label: 'Cheese', value: 'cheese' }, 
               { label: 'Tomatoes', value: 'tomatoes' }]
    }, {
    label: 'Second group',
    children: [{ label: 'Mozzarella', value: 'mozzarella' }, 
               { label: 'Mushrooms', value: 'mushrooms' }]
}];

$('.multiselect').multiselect('dataprovider', data);
```