# Multiselect grouping programmatically - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a table in this format:

[table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwZEH.png)

And i try to get this result programmatically:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNpld.jpg)

I'm using asp.net mvc with razor.
I know there is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273728) but i couldnt adapt in my situation :(
May you give an example please?

ADDED my work:

I think i must get the records via json, am i wrong? and im not good at in json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#ddl_Hours').multiselect();
</script>

<select id="ddl_Hours" multiple>
           @foreach (myModel item in ((MultiSelectList)ViewBag.MyList).Items)
           {
              int dayID = 0;

              if (dayID != item.DayID )
              {
                 <optgroup label="@item.DayID ">
                     <option value="@item.HourID">@item.Name</option>
                 </optgroup>
              }

              dayID = item.DayID;
            }
</select>
```

Controller:

```
var list = (from p in db.T_MYTABLE
            select new MyModel { HourID = p.HourID ,
                                 DayID = p.DayID,
                                 Name = p.Name 
                                }).ToList();

ViewBag.MyList= new MultiSelectList(list, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue) ? selectedValue.Split(',').ToArray() : null);
```

Comment: what have you tried? where is your code?

Comment: @MisaelMoneróThompson i added now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating such a grouped multi select using the jQuery plugin, first you need to render the HTML markup for grouped options like below

```
<select id="ddl_Hours">
    <optgroup label="4">
        <option value="1">00.00</option>
        <option value="2">01.00</option>
        <option value="3">02.00</option>
        <option value="4">03.00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2">
        <option value="5">04.00</option>
        <option value="6">05.00</option>
        <option value="7">06.0</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="3">
        <option value="8">07.00</option>
        <option value="9">08.00</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

To generate the above markup in your view, you can create a list of item's in your action method with the `Group` property.

```
var list = db.T_MYTABLE.ToList();

//Create a list of Groups
var groups = list.Select(x => x.DayId)
            .Select(f => new SelectListGroup() { Name = "Day " + f.ToString() }).ToList();

var groupedOptions = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.HourId.ToString(),
    Text = x.Name,
    Group = groups.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Day " + x.DayId.ToString())
}).ToList();

ViewBag.MyList = groupedOptions;

return View();
```

Assuming `Name` property of your entity is `string` type. If it is numeric type, use the `ToString()` method when setting the `Text` property value in the projection part of the above linq query (`Text=x.Name.ToString()`)

Now in your razor view, you can use the `Html.DropDownList` helper method to render the SELECT element.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddl_Hours", ViewBag.MyList as List<SelectListItem>)
```

or for the multi select

```
@Html.ListBox("ddl_Hours", ViewBag.MyList as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Now you can call your jQuery plugin to make it fancy. I would call it inside the document's `ready` event

```
$(function () {

    $('#ddl_Hours').multiselect();

})
```

and Voila!

[image]

Comment: really thank you but i use MVC 4. So selectListItem "Group" property not available in MVC 4. How can we convert your solution?

Comment: u r awesome really, do u have any idea for mvc 4? As i mentioned Group propert not working in mvc 4.

Comment: If it is not available in MVC4. you probably need to render the HTML I mentioned above using your custom code.

Comment: I really couldn't any solution.. how can display **optgroups** side by side?